# CSS change only background without duplicated class

Tags: css

I have this code below:

```
.prev, .next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 69px;
    height: 135px;
    margin-top: -68px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background: url(../images/slider-nav.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

I need these classes on home page but I need the same classes on about page but with another background. Which is the best way to do it. of course I can duplicate it and create for example class prevAbout and nextAbout but I think there is much better variant to do inherit or somehting like this.

I have added code but it just works for the prev class

```
.prev, .next, .prevClub {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 69px;
    height: 135px;
    margin-top: -68px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background: url(../images/slider-nav.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.prev:focus, .next:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.next {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    background-position: -75px 0;
}

.prevClub, nextClub {
    background: url(../images/slider-nav2.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.nextClub {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    background-position: -75px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

One way is to override the CSS and use a different image.

```
.prev, .next, .another-class {
    position: absolute;
    /* Etc... */
    background: url(../images/slider-nav.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.another-class {
    background: url(new image) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Another way is to scope them to an element up the hierarchy tree:

```
<body class="home">
  <!-- later down your html -->
  <a class="prev">prev</a>
</body>

<body class="about-us">
  <!-- later down your html -->
  <a class="prev">prev</a>
</body>

.prev, .next {
    position: absolute;
    /* Etc... */
}

.about-us .prev, .about-us .next {
    background: url(new image) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.home .prev, .home .next {
    background: url(new image) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Another way is to apply a common class then a specific class:

```
.nav-link {
  /* all common css goes here */
}

.home-prev-link {
  /* BG declaration here */
}

.about-prev-link {
  /* BG declaration here */
}
```

Then you can target them:

```
<a class="nav-link home-prev-link">Prev</a>
<a class="nav-link about-prev-link">Prev</a>
```

Comment: can you see my question I have updated my question? with your answer but it works just for prev

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander There's an error in your css: `.prevClub, nextClub {` Notice `nextClub`. There's no `.` for the class declaration.

Comment: yes, my mistake. fix it but without result. if I understood right nextClub will have all properties as the prev class but with another background. am I right?

Comment: Yes. Make sure the more specific declarations come after the common declarations, otherwise they'll get over written.

Answer (score 0):

Target the container they reside in on the about page and override the background image.

```
#about-container .prev, #about-container .next {
  background-image:url('image');
}
```